# Implementing Authentik as Single Sign-On (SSO) for Securing a Docusaurus Generated Static HTML

Tags: html, authentication, go, single-sign-on, docusaurus

I am developing a Go backend and using Docusaurus to generate a static HTML website. I would like to implement Authentik as a Single Sign-On (SSO) solution to secure the static HTML pages. Previously, I have set up OAuth and Keycloak for authentication in Go, but I am unsure how to configure Authentik for SSO and handle it in my Go middleware.

[Authentik](https://goauthentik.io/docs/)

Here are my specific questions:

1. What are the steps involved in integrating Authentik as a Single Sign-On (SSO) solution in a Go backend?
2. How can I enforce authentication using Authentik for my Docusaurus-generated static HTML pages?
3. Is it possible to handle Authentik-based authentication as middleware in Go to seamlessly authenticate requests for the static HTML content?
4. Are there any code examples or configuration settings available that can assist me in implementing Authentik SSO in my Go backend for securing the Docusaurus-generated static HTML?

Comment: Please ask one question per post.

Comment: Further, asking for code examples or other resources like this is off-topic on StackOverflow.